# XSL and schema match template condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0

How do I write a schema for the XML. What would be the schema for the xml I provided below. Below is my effort:

**I have the following XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <doc>
        <QQQ>hey</QQQ>
        <QQQ a1="1">hey1</QQQ>

        <PPP>hey</PPP>
        <PPP a1="1">hey1</PPP>
   </doc>
```

**Following XSL:**

```
  <xsl:template match="@a1[.='1']">
    <match>a1 is 1: <xsl:value-of select="."/></match>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*[local-name()='a1'][.='2']">
    <match>a1 is 2: <xsl:value-of select="."/></match>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Here is my work so far:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="QQQ" type="xsd:string">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="a1" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    </xsd:schema>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: want to write a schema for the xml and xsl so not sure how would I write that for the above.

Comment: What problems are you having with your current effort?  How does it fall short of your goals?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial problem is that you are saying two contradictory things about the element QQQ:  first you say that its type is xsd:string, and then you say that it has a complex type.  Stop contradicting yourself:  if you want QQQ to have an attribute, then you don't want it to have type string.

Any tutorial on XSD should help you further.  You'll get better responses here when you start encountering problems that aren't discussed in simple tutorials and thus don't invite answerers to say "RTFM".

Comment: I am new to this hence was stuck on it for a long time but after reading a good book I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't see what the XSLT code contributes to the problem description. Why are you telling us what your XSLT looks like? How do you expect this to affect the answer?

Secondly, there are many schemas to which your XML instance conforms. They differ in what other XML instances they allow in addition to your example. It's not really meaningful to write a schema for one XML instance, only for a family of similar instances.

It's also difficult to guess what constraints you are trying to express. For example, does a doc always consist of exactly two QQQ elements followed by exactly two PPP elements? Is it always the case that the a1 attribute is present on even-numbered child elements and absent on odd-numbered elements? Is it always the case that if the a1 attribute is present, then its value is the same as the last character of the element's content?

Writing the rules in English might be better than giving us an example. Write out: "Every doc follows the following rules:" and then write some rules, in English.

Comment: Good points. Thank you. This pointed me to somewhat right direction